# Opening a workbook and copying pages to master workbook

Tags: vba

I have this code which opens 2 workbooks, copies a sheet and paste then to the master workbook. It is currently taking 3 minutes.  Can this be done quicker (i.e. without opening each workbook to copy)?

It takes roughly 3 minutes to do.

```
Sub Load()
    Dim masterWB As Workbook
    Dim dailyWB As Workbook
    Dim lastweekWB As Workbook
    Dim R As Range
    Dim B As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim Lrow As Long

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Set Current Workbook as Master
    Set masterWB = Application.ThisWorkbook
    'Set some Workbook as the one you are copying from
    Set dailyWB = Workbooks.Open(Sheets("Control Manager").Range("O2"))

    'Copy the Range from dailyWB and Paste it into the MasterWB
    dailyWB.Sheets("Summary1").Range("A1:BJ200").Copy masterWB.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1").Rows("1:1")
    'formatting and paste as values
    masterWB.Activate
    Worksheets("Summary").Select
    'trim values
    Columns("A:BJ").Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'repeat for next Sheet
    dailyWB.Sheets("risk1").Range("A1:BB200").Copy masterWB.Sheets("risk").Range("A1").Rows("1:1")
    'formatting and paste as values'
    masterWB.Activate
    Worksheets("risk").Select
    Columns("A:BB").Select
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For Each B In Intersect(Columns("A:BB"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
            B.Value = .Trim(B.Value)
        Next B
    End With
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'repeat for CS sheet
    dailyWB.Sheets("CS today").Range("A1:L3").Copy masterWB.Sheets("CS").Range("A1").Rows("1:1")
    'formatting and paste as values
    masterWB.Activate
    Worksheets("CS").Select
    Columns("A:L").Select
    'trim cells to exclude spaces.
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For Each R In Intersect(Columns("A:L"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
            R.Value = .Trim(R.Value)
        Next R
    End With
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ''''''''''''Get Last Week Data''''''''''''''''''''''

    Set lastweekWB = Workbooks.Open(Sheets("Control Manager").Range("O3"))

    'repeat for next risk Sheet
    lastweekWB.Sheets("risk2").Range("A1:BB200").Copy masterWB.Sheets("risk_lastweek").Range("A1").Rows("1:1")
    'formatting and paste as values

    masterWB.Activate
    Worksheets("risk_lastweek").Select
    Columns("A:BB").Select
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For Each B In Intersect(Columns("A:BB"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
            B.Value = .Trim(B.Value)
        Next B
    End With
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Close the Workbook without saving
    dailyWB.Close False
    lastweekWB.Close False
    'Clear the Variables
    Set dailyWB = Nothing
    Set masterWB = Nothing
    Set lastweekWB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Separating tasks into multiple subroutines will make the code easier to test and modify.

This  video: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) will explain why you rarely need to Select or Activate an Object.

I would use `.Range("A1")` instead of `.Range("A1").Rows("1:1")` because `Range.Copy` targets the first cell in the destination.

### Refactored Code

```
Sub Load()
    LoadDailyWorkbook
    LoadLastWeeksWorkbook
End Sub

Sub LoadDailyWorkbook()
    Const A1BJ200 As String = "A1:BJ200"
    Const A1L3 As String = "A1:L3"
    Dim masterWB As Workbook
    Dim dailyWB As Workbook
    'Set Current Workbook as Master
    Set masterWB = Application.ThisWorkbook
    'Set some Workbook as the one you are copying from
    Set dailyWB = getWorkbook(Sheets("Control Manager").Range("O2"))

    If Not dailyWB Is Nothing Then
        With dailyWB
            'Copy the Range from dailyWB and Paste it into the MasterWB
            .Worksheets("Summary1").Range(A1BJ200).Copy masterWB.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1")
            TrimRange masterWB.Worksheets("Summary").Range(A1BJ200)
            'repeat for next Sheet
            .Worksheets("risk1").Range(A1BJ200).Copy masterWB.Worksheets("risk").Range("A1")
            TrimRange masterWB.Worksheets("risk").Range(A1BJ200)

            'repeat for CS sheet
            .Worksheets("CS today").Range(A1L3).Copy masterWB.Worksheets("CS").Range("A1").Rows("1:1")
            TrimRange masterWB.Worksheets("CS").Range(A1L3)
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With

    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadLastWeeksWorkbook()
    Const A1BJ200 As String = "A1:BJ200"
    Dim masterWB As Workbook
    Dim lastweekWB As Workbook

    'Set Current Workbook as Master
    Set masterWB = Application.ThisWorkbook

    ''''''''''''Get Last Week Data''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set lastweekWB = getWorkbook(Workbooks.Open(Sheets("Control Manager").Range("O3")))
    If Not lastweekWB Is Nothing Then
        With lastweekWB
            'repeat for next risk Sheet
            .Worksheets("risk2").Range(A1BJ200).Copy masterWB.Worksheets("risk_lastweek").Range("A1")
            TrimRange masterWB.Worksheets("risk_lastweek").Range(A1BJ200)

            TrimRange masterWB.Columns("A:BB")
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Function getWorkbook(FullName As String) As Workbook
    If Len(Dir(FullName)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox FullName & " not found found", vbCritical, "File Not Found"
    Else
        Set getWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FullName)
    End If
End Function

Sub TrimRange(Target As Range)
    Dim results As Variant
    Set Target = Intersect(Target.Parent.UsedRange, Target)
    If Target Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Target.Count = 1 Then
        Target.Value = Trim(Target.Value)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        results = Target.Value

        Dim r As Long, c As Long
        For r = 1 To UBound(results)
            For c = 1 To UBound(results, 2)
                results(r, c) = Trim(results(r, c))
            Next
        Next
        Target.Value = results
    End If
    Target.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this, getting `type mismatch` error on `Set Target = Intersect(Target.Parent, Target)`

Comment: @excelguy I updated the code.  Should have been `Target.Parent.UsedRange`.

Comment: overflow error now lol, `Target = Target.Value`

Comment: Hmmm....I've been writing javascript so I put  `Else If` instead of `ElseIf `  but it should be a syntax error.  I don't know why you would get an overflow error.

Comment: Not sure either, ill look into it.

Comment: @excelguy I can't believe I made that mistake.  Anyway `Target= Target.Value` should be `results = Target.Value`

Comment: lol now im getting error on `results = Target.Value`

Comment: @excelguy are there any errors in the range (e.g. `#N/A`,`#NULL!`, `#REF!`, `#DIV/0!`)?

Comment: weirdly I get my overflow error once I step past `Set getWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FullName)` . So open the workbook opens I get the overflow error. I can open the workbook manually and I do not get the error. So it looks like it doesnt even get to the copy and paste part of the code yet. But for some reason the error is on `results = Target.Value`

Comment: That's very strange